# Where to place delegates in a storyboard popover

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

In my app I had a Storyboard with a UIViewController. In the View of the UIViewController I had several buttons that had a popover action. The user would get a popover and choose from some options, then the popover would be dismissed. In the UIViewController I had my segue and my delegates to intercept the value and load it into my data model.

I just added a container in the UIViewController which has a TableView with my buttons in the cells. This looks MUCH better. Although my popovers still works, my delegate doesn't.

I knew somehow that the delegates would break, but I do not understand exactly why or how to fix it.

What should I do to fix this and what are the best practices for delegate patterns.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same class which confirms delegates for your tableView should also confirms for Popover delegates.

Comment: I am a little confused by this.

Comment: Is your new container a separate class right? Which controls tableview and your buttons' behavior.

Comment: I didn't make the new container a class. I did that, and then moved the delegates there, and that is working fine now!